# How to use FOR EACH type functionality in a SQL query?

Tags: sql, for-loop, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report that returns a page for a specific order using that orders information.  My users want to be able to select multiple orders, and be able to scroll through.  I changed the parameter to select multiple values and populated the list with a query to show all orders.

My problem is that when I select multiple orders, it throws all the information from all the orders on to one sheet, whereas I want it to return the page with information for each specific order on a different page.

Is there a FOR EACH/loop type functionality I can incorporate to run this in interation?

Let me know if you need pictures or code.  Here's what I essentially have now:

```
SELECT
info
FROM table
WHERE conditions
AND order_no in (:OrderNo)
```

Comment: You don't do that in SQL. You do it in SSRS by grouping it on the order id field and setting a group page break.

Comment: That doesn't quite work.  It throws the information from both orders into the designated spots, but just breaks the page between two fields.  I need the report to run separately per order.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "I need the report to run separately per order" because in your question, you said you want "to return the page with information for each specific order on a different page" and that's what a page break on the group will do. You will need to be more clear about your requirements if that's not what you want.

Comment: Typically, the user selects a single order # and runs the report.  The report pulls in fields associated with that order # and puts them on the report in designated spots, let's say "order address" and "order quantity" are somewhere on the page.  When I select "allow multiple values" on the parameter properties, and populate the possible values with all the order #s, selecting multiple orders acts as if it is trying to put all the addresses and quantities in the same spot on one report.  I want it to create an individual report for each order, but multiple reports at once.

Comment: So, for example, I have the order # field somewhere on the report.  Currently, it throws an error when selecting multiple, because it doesn't know which order # to select, since it isn't making one report page per order.

Comment: @DominicG. what is the error message shown when selecting multiple?

Comment: @DominicG. your report items (textboxes etc) are probably all placed directly on the report design surface at the moment. If you want to handle multiple records, you'll need to put all these items inside another report item that supports grouping, such as a List.